# How can I store a screenshot from an object to a string and save the image into an excel worksheet in selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, automation, apache-poi

I have a simple selenium WebDriver program that reads the excel file data and performs login functionality.

I require to take a screenshot whenever the test case fails and save it into the excel worksheet cell.

To accomplish read and writing excel, I have already created the code. I have also written a program that captures screenshots and saves them with unique names. This program is in a separate class in the utility package, which I call into the MAIN method using its instance/object.

I want to store the object of the FailedTestScreenCapture class into a string variable and extract the image captured from inside this object, then save it in the excel worksheet.

Below is the code that I have created to capture screenshots and save them with unique names.

```
package utilities;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler;

import org.junit.rules.MethodRule;
import org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class FailedTestScreenCapture implements MethodRule {

WebDriver driver;

    public FailedTestScreenCapture(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public Statement apply(final Statement statement, final FrameworkMethod frameworkMethod, final Object obj) {
        // Auto-generated method stub
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                    statement.evaluate();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    // handle exception
                    captureScreen(frameworkMethod.getName());
                    throw t;
                }
            }

            public void captureScreen(String screenShot) {
                // creating a screenshot method
                try {
                    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
                    File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                    screenShot += UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    FileHandler.copy(source, new File("./Screenshots/" + screenShot + ".jpg"));
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("An exception occured while taking the screenshot" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Below is the code that reads and writes the excel worksheet.

```
package view;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import utilities.ExcelUtils;
import utilities.FailedTestScreenCapture;
import utilities.Constants;

public class OTMGeneral {
    static WebDriver driver;



// creating object of ExcelUtils class
    static ExcelUtils excelUtils = new ExcelUtils();
    static FailedTestScreenCapture failedTstCase = new FailedTestScreenCapture(driver);

    // using the constants class values for excel file path
    static String excelFilePath = Constants.Path_TestData + Constants.File_TestData;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.chromeDriverPath);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // maximize the browser screen
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to(Constants.BaseUrl);

        // wait for the browser to load resources
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));

        // Identify the WebElements for OTM Login
        WebElement continueBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button"));
        WebElement loginBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div/div/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a"));

        // landing page pop-up message
        WebElement popupMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div"));

        // click the sing-in button
        if (popupMsg.isDisplayed()) {
            // if the pop-up is displayed, click the continue button
            continueBtn.click();

            // wait for page to come back to landing page after continue button is clicked
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));

            // click the login button
            loginBtn.click();
        } else {
            loginBtn.click();
        }

        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
        WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("Password"));
        WebElement signInBtn = driver.findElement(By.id("btnlogin"));

        // calling ExcelUtils class method to initialize the workbook and sheet
        excelUtils.setExcelFile(excelFilePath, "Login_Data");

        for (int i = 1; i <= excelUtils.getRowCountInSheet(); i++) {

            if (i > 1) {
                // Handling staled elements by refreshing the screen
                driver.navigate().refresh();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div/div/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

                driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(excelUtils.getCellData(i, 0));
                driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(excelUtils.getCellData(i, 1));

                driver.findElement(By.id("btnlogin")).click();

            } else {

                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
                // Enter the value read from excel in email and password fields
                email.sendKeys(excelUtils.getCellData(i, 0));
                pwd.sendKeys(excelUtils.getCellData(i, 1));

                // click on login button
                signInBtn.click();
            }

            // wait after login button clicked
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));

            // check for login pass or fail
            boolean helloCustomer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div/div/nav/div/ul/li[1]/a"))
                    .getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Regístrate");
            System.out.println(helloCustomer);

            if (!helloCustomer) {

                // capture the result in the excel sheet
                excelUtils.setCellValue(i, 2, "Pass", excelFilePath);
                System.out.println("login pass");
                // Identify logout button
                WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.id("logout"));
                logout.click();
            } else {
                excelUtils.setCellValue(i, 2, "Fail", excelFilePath);
                System.out.println("login fail");
                // capture screenshot when a test case fails
                excelUtils.setCellValue(i, 3, failedTstCase.toString(), excelFilePath);
            }

            // wait for page to come back to registration page after logout button is
            // clicked
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
        }
        // closing the driver
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to attach the image if a test fails. Is that correct? If yes, why do you want to do that because it increases your excel size and may lead into performance issues.

Comment: @NandanA Yes, I want to attach a screenshot image when the test case fails. I want to do it because it is a requirement. Despite I am aware of the fact that it will increase the excel size.

Comment: Posted an answer. I would like to hear feedback from you back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by converting the image into `byte[]` then draw the image in desired location. You can do like this,

**In your `OTMGeneral` class**:

```
if (!helloCustomer) {
    //Your code
} else {
    excelUtils.setCellValue(i, 2, "Fail", excelFilePath);
    System.out.println("login fail");
    // capture screenshot when a test case fails
    excelUtils.attachImageToExcel("NameOfScreenshot", i, 3,  0.3);
}
```

Keep the method `attachImageToExcel` in your `ExcelUtils`. You need to pass the below `@Params`.

```
@Param screenShot - The name what you assigned to the image while capturing.
@Param column     - Column number
@Param row        - Row number
@Param image size - Pass the float value. Example 0.3 = 30% image
```

**Code**:

```
public static void attachImageToExcel(String screenShot, int column, int row, double imageSize)
        throws Exception {

    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("FileLocation")));
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("SheetName");

    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("./Screenshots/" + screenShot + ".jpg");
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
    inputStream.close();

    CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
    anchor.setCol1(column);
    anchor.setRow1(row);

    Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
    pict.resize(imageSize);

    FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
    fileOut = new FileOutputStream((new File("FileLocation")));
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: You need to add the file location as well inside `attachImageToExcel`

Comment: Thank you for the effort you made to address my problem. However, the solution you proposed is not working in my current program. You're a great person, and I appreciate the time and knowledge you put to answer this question.

Comment: Welcome.. the solution you proposed is not working in my current program. What is the issue? If it throwing some errors please let me know I can help you.

Comment: In my code, I have a method called `setCellValue()`. This method has four arguments `int rowNum`, `int cellNum`, `String cellValue`, and `String excelFilePath` respectively. 
I want to create such a program that can fit into the third argument i.e. `String cellValue`. Through this variable, I am writing the results into my excel sheet.
I have tried a lot of functions to accomplish this, however, nothing worked.

Comment: There are two main goals;
1. Past screenshots to the target cell in the sheet using the `String cellValue` variable.
2. Save screenshots with dynamic names, so that not every other screenshot must overwrite the first one.

Comment: You can use this method but you need to modify little bit to make it fit for your problem.

Comment: I modified your code and called the function `attachImageToExcel()` in `setCellValue()`. However, that did not work.
What I want to do is to pass the method into a String type variable and extract the image afterward. This variable I want to pass as an argument in my `setCellValue()` method.
Please share your thoughts if you have a solution.

Comment: Like I explained above, my requirement from the beginning has been the same. The class that I pasted in my question that is taking a screenshot, I want to pass its object into a String type variable. After that I want to extract the screenshots from this string and pass it in the `setCellValue()` as an argument.

Comment: Sorry.. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I have tried a way around. However, my solution is still not working. Please see below the code that I created to store the `FailedTestScreenCapture` class object into a `byte[]` then convert this `byte[]` to a string and pass the string in my `setCellValue` method.

Comment: ``ByteArrayOutputStream outPutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();``
`ObjectOutputStream objOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outPutStream);`
`objOutStream.writeObject(failedTstCase);`
`objOutStream.flush();`
`byte[] screenCapture = outPutStream.toByteArray();`
`String capturedScreen = new String(screenCapture);`
`excelUtils.setCellValue(i, 3, capturedScreen, excelFilePath);`

Comment: Sorry Jamil.. I couldn't able to understand the logic what you are trying to implement. In simple words I can say... Now you have a method to add the image into Excel and all you need to pass is screenshot name (dynamic name for every screenshot) you can use this a new method instead of changing your existing methods.